# Git push to upstream, specific sections of specific files

Tags: git, gitlab, git-fork

### Context:

I have a local instance of gitlab running on one of my private servers. (no cloud involvement)

There is a webapp project repo. Let's call it A. A containes a base set of functionality theme etc. which is meant to remain uniform accross the organization. The goal is to have A in a stable state, with very common functions that any team that wants to build a webapp, simply needs to "fork" A so that they end up with the base level features, and can continue to build out their specific features.

### Scenario:

I fork project A and call the project B. Now B contains all of A. I start adding a lot of specific functionality to B. At some point in time I realize that a certain feature is going to make a lot of sense being in A, as a base feature.

### Questions:

1. How do I go about pushing just this feature to back to upstream A, which will most likely be a lot of commits behind B?
2. Is fork-and-build approach really a fiesable way to go about doing something like this?

Comment: Git does not push *files* in the first place. Git pushes *commits*. Every commit has a full snapshot of every file—not a set of changes, but a full snapshot. So if you want to push "a change" to a file, you must take the original file, make a new version that has the one part changed, make a new commit that has every original file as is except for that one file where you use the new file, and push that. This is what Git does all the time anyway: when you modify one file in your working tree, run `git add` on it, and run `git commit`, you get a new snapshot of *all* files, including that one.

Comment: Each snapshot carefully *de-duplicates* all the files in advance, so that the repository size does not grow huge after just a few commits. Git has further compression tricks that kick in later, too, but this alone suffices for a lot of things. So the fact that every commit has a full copy of every file doesn't make a lot of *space* difference—but it means you should think of commits as snapshots/archives, because they *are*.

Comment: Every clone has every commit. A fork is just a clone where the hosting site (in your case a private GitLab one) does something to make it easy for you to make "pull requests" to some *other* clone that is hosted on the same site. (The pull requests are features of the specific site, and GitLab, GitHub, and Bitbucket all have some relatively minor differences behind the scenes here. Neither fork nor pull request are in base Git, they're all site add-ons. This doesn't matter much for using them, but keep it in mind if you ever want to migrate to a different hosting system.)